# SQL statement with an impossible constant comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE 2=3;
```

Obviously, the query will return 0 rows, but my question is as follows. Does the SQL Server engine evaluate the where condition before executing the selection?

In other words, does SQL Server detect the where condition is impossible and return 0 rows automatically?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7983/does-where-1-1-usually-have-an-impact-on-query-performance

Answer (score 9):

If you examine the execution plan for a simple query using such a predicate you will see that SQL Server uses a `Constant Scan` to determine that zero results will return. No indexes or tables are even touched.

```
SELECT * FROM [Production].[Product];
SELECT * FROM [Production].[Product] WHERE 1=0;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically order is given [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/)

This is order of query execution at SQL:

> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. OUTER
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. CUBE | ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT 10 ORDER BY
> 10. TOP