# Is it possible to prevent SQL from joining when condition is always false?

Tags: sql, optimization, sql-server-2012

Consider the following

```
declare @flag bit = 1

select *
from a
  left join b
    on a.id = b.id
   and @flag = 0
```

Ideally, I might break this into two stored procedures: one for when @flag is true and another for when it's false. However, in my case there is a massive query that I'm just hoping to make a couple of quick optimizations to where I can find some low hanging fruit.

The idea is obviously that I don't SQL wasting time joining to table b under certain conditions, but that's not how SQL works. Are there other ways to make this kind of an optimization or is breaking it up into multiple procs with and without the join the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried running this?  SQL Server may be smart enough to optimize the join.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL statement with an impossible constant comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453161/sql-statement-with-an-impossible-constant-comparison)

Comment: @iamdave That question is similar, however the primary difference is that I am left joining to another table and so it will always return all results for table a. In the other question it could potentially return no results. And if it returns results for a then it will have to return null values for all columns of table b and I don't think it can do that without joining to it (though I'm not certain about that).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did try it and it didn't work... however my first attempt involved a table valued function on the right side of the join (for a full text search) and so I made a bad assumption. Just tried it again with an outer join on two regular tables and I see that you are absolutely right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your method on the AdventureWorks database and it works fine. Looking at the IO, SQL performs 0 reads of the table.

The key thing I would do is add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the end of your query, because SQL may reuse an inappropriate Plan in the Cache.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work in my initial test (as explained in comment on the post) but I stupidly didn't bother to actually test the simplified example I made before posting though. Thanks a lot for the OPTION (RECOMPILE) tip.